# Is there a way to remove a custom tag and replace it with a default one?

Tags: macos, finder-tag

Let's suppose that I created a new tag "custom tag".
Is there a way to not only delete said tag, but also relabel all files which were previously labeled with that tag with a default one, like blue, red, green... automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the custom tag last…

First, open a new finder window & from the sidebar set it to show the files with the tag you wish to replace.

Select all files in there -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  - then right click & add your desired default tag.
With them all still selected, right click & remove the custom tag. They will vanish from the window at that point, but they will have moved to the new tag you assigned.

Then, in Finder prefs > tags, click the tag you want to delete & hit the  <kbd>-</kbd>  button underneath.

Tried to squeeze all that into one explanatory picture…

[image]